# Serving Excel File in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I'm in Internet Explorer 8, using MVC 1 and IIS 7.

I have an action on a controller which serves up an excel file.

I go to the action, a dialog pops up asking if I want to save or open the file, and I select open.

Then Excel makes a HEAD request to the server, followed by opening up a password prompt, then goes up a directory and makes an OPTIONS request, followed by 5 PROPFIND requests.  Then if I cancel the password prompt, the excel document opens fine, and makes one final HEAD request to the original directory.

What is going on, and how do I stop it?  Can I do something in global.asax or my web.config to mass block all these HEAD/OPTIONS/PROPFIND requests that excel is making?  I don't have access to make changes to the web server.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs in office documents where the microsoft programs try to open the file from the server itself. It then tries to authenticate and sends requests such as OPTIONS and PROPFIND to get the server type and tool available to do live editing and updating the local copy from the server, etc. Basically, its done for synchronization.

How do you stop it? no idea, probably have to look at the settings in your local excel tool.

How do you block specific requests in global.ascx? Whats the advantage of blocking it instead of just leaving it, its not like your application is using the request anyways. I'd like to see an answer for this though.

Comment: It doesn't cause any serious problems, but it's cluttering up our error logs with these stupid requests.  And the password prompt isn't acceptable.

Comment: The prompt cannot be stopped from the server end, neither the requests, it is a feature built in office tools.

Comment: On How to block specific verbs??  -- One option couldbe that You create a HttpHandler and specify the types of verb it accepts..

Comment: There is no reason for the password prompt.  The user clicks cancel and can still view the document.